# Neo4j - How to create a unique node and set a label in the same batch operation

Tags: json, rest, neo4j

Can I create a unique node and set a label in the same batch operation?

I tried to do with this json but unfortunately the server fails

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "method": "POST",
        "to": "/index/node/PhoneBook?uniqueness=get_or_create",
        "body": {
            "key": "mobilePhone",
            "value": "9999999999",
            "properties": {
                "firstName": "fn1",
                "lastName": "ln1",
                "mobilePhone": "9999999999"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "POST",
        "to": "{0}/labels",
        "body": [
            "Contact"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please provide a stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cypher instead:

```
MERGE (p:PhoneBook {mobilePhone:{phoneNo}} 
ON CREATE SET p += {properties}, SET p:Contact
```

params:

```
       {phoneNo: "9999999999", "properties": {
            "firstName": "fn1",
            "lastName": "ln1",
            "mobilePhone": "9999999999"
        }
```